# Echoing images only when logged in as admin

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Right now, using PHP, I'm using this code to echo images that are uploaded to a database.

```
<?php
include "config.php"; //database connection
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data");
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()):
?>

<div class="media">

 <a class="media-left" href="#">
 </a>
<div class="img">

  <a target="_blank" onclick="window.open('upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>','<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>')">

    <img width="300" height="200" src="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>" alt="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>"></a>  
</div>
</div>
```

The above code works fine as it is, but I want to only show the images section when the admin is logged in. I've tried achieving what I want like so,

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) 

            {echo '
<div class="media">

 <a class="media-left" href="#">
 </a>
<div class="img">

  <a target="_blank" onclick="window.open(\'upload/<?php echo $row[\'file_name\'] ?>\',\'<?php echo $row[\'file_name\'] ?>\')">

    <img width="300" height="200" src="upload/<?php echo $row[\'file_name\'] ?>" alt="upload/<?php echo $row[\'file_name\'] ?>"></a>  
</div>
</div>';       
    }
?>
```

while this does what I need, the images that are called from the database aren't displayed. Just empty boxes like so: 
[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in php code already so not:

```
src="upload/<?php echo $row[\'file_name\'] ?>"
```

but:

```
src="upload/'.$row['file_name'].'"
```

ps: the same with other parts of your code you showed us

Comment: Like so?  <a target="_blank" onclick="window.open("upload/'.$row['file_name'].'" , '$row['file_name'] . ')">

    <img width="300" height="200" src="upload/'.$row['file_name'].'" alt="upload/'.$row['file_name'].'"></a>

This just throws me a syntax error. I can't find it.

Comment: no, now you have parse errors.... `<a target="_blank" onclick="window.open(\'upload/'.$row['file_name'].'\' , \''.$row['file_name'] . '\')"> <img width="300" height="200" src="upload/'.$row['file_name'].'" alt="upload/'.$row['file_name'].'"></a> `

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Sorry, I'm still a noob in PHP.